# getting error on running google glass compass

Tags: google-glass

I want to execute compass sample program in google glasses but i always getting this error..
But i run the stop watch and timer, It will working good..
Tell the solution pls..

```
`[2014-06-07 19:54:26 - Compass] Dx `
`trouble writing output: already prepared`
`[2014-06-07 19:54:26 - Compass] ------------------------------`
`[2014-06-07 19:54:26 - Compass] Android Launch!`
`[2014-06-07 19:54:26 - Compass] adb is running normally.`
`[2014-06-07 19:54:26 - Compass] No Launcher activity found!`
`[2014-06-07 19:54:26 - Compass] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!`
`[2014-06-07 19:54:26 - Compass] Performing sync`
`[2014-06-07 19:54:26 - Compass] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator emulator-5556 running compatible AVD AVD_for_Glass
 [2014-06-07 19:54:26 - Compass] Uploading Compass.apk onto device emulator-5556'
 [2014-06-07 19:54:26 - Compass] Installing Compass.apk...`
`[2014-06-07 19:54:29 - Compass] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY`

`[2014-06-07 19:54:29 - Compass] Please check logcat output for more details.`
`[2014-06-07 19:54:29 - Compass] Launch canceled!`
```

Comment: Are you targeting "Glass Development Kit Preview:19" in the project properties of the Compass project ?

target=Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19

Comment: yes that only.. gettting error in that compass project only..

Comment: Typically, Glass APKs are pushed to a Glass device, not an emulator. I can't tell what might be missing in an emulator vs a real device. Also, this question probably shouldn't be tagged "android-wear"

Comment: oh.. that's the mistake.. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

DisplayMetrics gives this output on Glass Explorer edition:

DisplayMetrics{density=1.5, width=640, height=360, scaledDensity=1.5, xdpi=180.62222, ydpi=169.33333}

So it does indeed look like hdpi.

Also the screen size is small:

....

```
else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {     
    Log.d(TAG,"SMALL screen");
}
```

And it is "notlong" in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Glass development on an emulator isn't currently supported

You can check out this issue which is the same (I would actually close the question and point it there)

[Is there any way to run glassware in an emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083974/is-there-any-way-to-run-glassware-in-an-emulator)