# Configure Google Glass as Android Studio AVD

Tags: android-studio, google-glass, android-virtual-device

Anyone know if it is possible to configure the **google glass** as **AVD** to run programs on **Android Studio**?

Comment: AVD means Android Virtual Devices. So if you try to configure a real Google glass as an AVD, it doesn't mean anything. If you're instead trying to configure an AVD to match the Google Glass, there is unfortunately no official support for it.

Comment: My question is if there is any way to create a virtual environment that simulates Google Glass on Android Studio. I saw in many places that is possible install a simulator directly in the real Android device. @SimonMarquis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simulate a Google Glass device with AVD. You can only create a device with the same hardware specifications that Google Glass, but you can't install the Google Glass specific libraries.

Even with Genymotion you can't at the moment.

Here is a post which talk about it: [Is there any way to run glassware in an emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083974/is-there-any-way-to-run-glassware-in-an-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

For the **Google Glass EE2** there is a profile available in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass-enterprise/guides/get-started#hardware-profile).

The direct link to GitHub is:
https://github.com/googlesamples/glass-enterprise-samples/blob/master/HardwareProfile/glass_ee2_hardware_profile.xml